# null point exception when trying to fetch data from openweathermap

Tags: java, android, json, openweathermap

I am trying to get sunrise and sunset time for my current location from `openweathermap` api. I am following [this](https://www.androstock.com/tutorials/create-a-weather-app-on-android-android-studio.htmlhttps://www.androstock.com/tutorials/create-a-weather-app-on-android-android-studio.html) tutorial.

I have copied the entire `Function.java` in the tutorial and trying to use the data to update my ViewPagerAdapter's Fragment.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    TextView cityField = getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_city);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

        RecyclerView rv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
        rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);


        Function.placeIdTask asyncTask =new Function.placeIdTask(new Function.AsyncResponse() {
            public void processFinish(String weather_city, String weather_description, String weather_temperature, String weather_humidity, String weather_pressure, String weather_updatedOn, String weather_iconText, String sun_rise) {

                cityField.setText(weather_city);
             }
        });
        asyncTask.execute("25.180000", "89.530000"); //  asyncTask.execute("Latitude", "Longitude")
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new String[]{"Hello", "World"});
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and I have named my target for the city name as `tv_city`:

```
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_city"
        android:layout_toRightOf ="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:gravity="top" >
    </TextView>
```

The problem is, possibly I am making some mistake to fetch the data, as I am getting nul exception error for this line:

```
TextView cityField = getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
```

as:

```
Process: com.example.phocast, PID: 9820                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
     at com.example.phocast.BlankFragment.<init>(BlankFragment.java:17)
```

WIth my limited knowledge in java, I am unable to solve it.
Kindly help.

**Update**
actually, writing oncreateview as:

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);

```
RecyclerView rv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);


Weather_OWM.placeIdTask asyncTask =new Weather_OWM.placeIdTask(new Weather_OWM.AsyncResponse() {
    public void processFinish(String weather_city, String weather_description, String weather_temperature, String weather_humidity, String weather_pressure, String weather_updatedOn, String weather_iconText, String sun_rise) {

       TextView cityField = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
       cityField.setText(weather_city);
     }
});
```

solves my problem, but i dont know if this is proper/good way to use final. I will be really grateful if someone shows me the way before closing it.

Comment: I suggest that you research the Activity and Fragment lifecycles.

Answer (score 0):

Your cityView line of code is just hanging out there, not in a method or anything. The NullPointer is coming from getView(). You can't find the view before onCreateView occurs and the inflater does its thing. Move it to onCreateView, anytime after `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);`

Answer (score 0):

You need initialize the textView after:

`View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);`

After initialize the recyclerView you can write this:

`cityField = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);`